# How to add background image to Entry in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

my designer created a background image to style the inputs it looks like this:

[image]

How could I accomplish that in Xamarin.Forms?
The easy part I'm guessing is removing the border, but I also need to position it on top of that image (I'd assume using RelativeLayout?) and the hardest (in my point of view) setting its proper size to "fill" the remaining of the image.
I'm using XAML, but if you know in C# I can extrapolate that, no problem.
Any ideas?

EDIT:
This is what I've managed to do so far:
[image]

The code:

```
<RelativeLayout>
  <Image Source="input_selected.png"></Image>
  <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
    <Image Source="ico_password.png" Scale="0.7"></Image>
    <Entry x:Name="PasswordT" Placeholder="Senha" IsPassword="True" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Text=""></Entry>
  </StackLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="LoginPage"
             Style="{StaticResource LoginBackground}">
  <ScrollView>
    <RelativeLayout x:Name="RelativeLayoutLogin">
      <StackLayout x:Name="BackgroundLayout" Spacing="15" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Start">
        <StackLayout.Padding>
          <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" iOS="15, 38, 15, 15" Android="15, 18, 15, 15" WinPhone="15, 18, 15, 15" />
        </StackLayout.Padding>
        <StackLayout.Children>
          <Image Source="logo.png" Aspect="AspectFit" HeightRequest="75"></Image>
          <Image x:Name="BackgroundBox" Source="box_completo.png" Aspect="AspectFill"></Image>
        </StackLayout.Children>
      </StackLayout>

      <StackLayout RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, ElementName=BackgroundLayout, Property=Y, Constant=111}"
                   RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, ElementName=BackgroundLayout, Property=Width, Factor=1}">
        <!--<StackLayout.Padding>
          <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" iOS="15, 38, 15, 15" Android="15, 18, 15, 15" WinPhone="15, 18, 15, 15" />
        </StackLayout.Padding>-->
        <RelativeLayout>
          <Image Source="input.png" x:Name="BgUsername"></Image>
          <Image Source="input_selected.png" x:Name="SelectedBgUsername" IsVisible="False"></Image>
          <StackLayout RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant, Constant=8}"
                    RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant, Constant=8}"
                    RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Constant=-16}"
                    RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Constant=-16}"
                    Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="ico_user.png" Scale="0.6"></Image>
            <Entry x:Name="UsernameOrEmail" Placeholder="Nome de usuário" IsEnabled="True" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Text="" TextColor="Black"></Entry>
          </StackLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout>
          <Image Source="input.png" x:Name="BgPassword"></Image>
          <Image Source="input_selected.png" x:Name="SelectedBgPassword" IsVisible="False"></Image>
          <StackLayout RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant, Constant=8}"
                      RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant, Constant=8}"
                      RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Constant=-16}"
                      RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Constant=-16}"
                      Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="ico_password.png" Scale="0.6"></Image>
            <Entry x:Name="Password" Placeholder="Senha" IsPassword="True" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Text="" TextColor="Black"></Entry>
          </StackLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <!--<RelativeLayout Scale="0.85">
          <Image Source="input.png" x:Name="BgUsername"></Image>
          <Image Source="input_selected.png" x:Name="SelectedBgUsername" IsVisible="False"></Image>
          <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="15, 5, 0, 0">
            <Image Source="ico_user.png" Scale="0.6"></Image>
            <Entry x:Name="UsernameOrEmail" Placeholder="Nome de usuário" IsEnabled="True" WidthRequest="300" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Text="" TextColor="Black"></Entry>
          </StackLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout Scale="0.85">
          <Image Source="input.png" x:Name="BgPassword"></Image>
          <Image Source="input_selected.png" x:Name="SelectedBgPassword" IsVisible="False"></Image>
          <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="10, 5, 0, 0">
            <Image Source="ico_password.png" Scale="0.6"></Image>
            <Entry x:Name="Password" Placeholder="Senha" IsPassword="True" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" WidthRequest="300" Text="" TextColor="Black"></Entry>
          </StackLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>-->
        <Image x:Name="LoginButtonFm" Style="{StaticResource FmLoginButton}" Scale="0.85"></Image>
        <Label Text="OU" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"></Label>
        <Image x:Name="LoginButtonFacebook" Style="{StaticResource FacebookLoginButton}" Scale="0.85"></Image>
        <Image x:Name="LoginButtonGoogle" Style="{StaticResource GoogleLoginButton}" Scale="0.85"></Image>
        <Image x:Name="LoginButtonTwitter" Style="{StaticResource TwitterLoginButton}" Scale="0.85"></Image>
      </StackLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're definitely on the right track. Just need to add a few constraints to one of the `View`s in your `RelativeLayout`.

```
<RelativeLayout>
  <Image Source="input_selected.png"></Image>
    <StackLayout
      RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant, Constant=8}"
      RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant, Constant=8}"
      RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Constant=-16}"
      RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant, Constant=48}"
      Orientation="Horizontal">
      <Image Source="ico_password.png" Scale="0.7"></Image>
      <Entry x:Name="PasswordT" Placeholder="Senha" IsPassword="True" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Text="offspring"></Entry>
    </StackLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

That will position the StackLayout to fill the entire RelativeLayout with 8dpx padding on each side. Then because the `Entry` is set to `FillAndExpand`, it will take up all the space in the `StackLayout` not occupied by ico_password.

Comment: Thanks Joel, but I might've misunderstood something... this is how it looks after inserting your constraints: http://i.imgur.com/T17J5d2.png As you can see the input not only pushed the icon, but also went downwards.

Comment: @eestein sorry to hear that didn't work. It looks like the RelativeLayout may be taking up the whole space, which makes sense depending upon what kind of container it's in. If you put it in, say, a StackLayout and give it a HeightRequest and a WidthRequest that match the dimensions (in dip) of input_selected.png, does the layout line up better?

Comment: Hey Joel, please check EDIT2, that's my complete code. I was able to make it look like this: http://i.imgur.com/A2hWBwU.png using padding and scale as you can see in the commented code, before testing your code I commented all my changes so they wouldn't mess with your solution. Does seeing the code help?

Comment: @eestein thanks for posting the full XAML. I'll fire it up in VS as soon as I get a chance and see if I can figure out what I'm missing.

Comment: @eestein, I updated my answer to set the height of the StackLayout explicitly rather than filling its container since there are multiple StackLayouts inside the same RelativeLayout. I can't be sure it'll work without the image assets since they in some ways determine the layout, but I think that it might help.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm still new to forms so I haven't mastered RelativeLayout yet. One extra question, the inputs show a white background on my WP emulator, do you how can I remove that? On my android device it doesn't show, so I'm guessing it could be a bug in the emulator. Thanks again!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83150/discussion-between-joel-anair-and-eestein).