# Is there anyway to add a icon in the Entry placeholder?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I can not use a Background Image because cannot fix the position of the start point.the placeholder text is centered.so it is not duplicated.

How to add an icon in the placeholder of an `Entry` beside using `Grid` or `Layout`. Just add it in the placeholder.

I want to make an `Entry` with placeholder containing an icon . Which is center in the `Entry` so that I can not use grid or layout to add a Image because this is not the best way.

I think I will have to make clicked event functions of the Image and the entry focus to hide the Image.

The expected result is like that:
[Entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvZB9.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add background image to Entry in Xamarin.Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31348870/how-to-add-background-image-to-entry-in-xamarin-forms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first way I can think of doing this:

If the icon you would like to use is a generic icon, [FontAwesome](https://fontawesome.com/) is a fantastic fontkit that displays icons in the place of text. I have implemented it into Xamarin Forms many times. Here are some tutorials on how to do that:

https://www.wintellect.com/using-fontawesome5-xamarin-forms/

https://doumer.me/icons-with-font-awesome-5-xamarin-forms/

What you would do is set the FontFamily of the entry field to FontAwesome, and then add a textchanged event on text length > 0 change the fontfamily to your normal font, on text length = 0 (Place holder displayed) Change font family to FontAwesome.

The second way I can think of doing this:

Create a [Xamarin Forms Custom Renderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/) for all of the platforms you are using. whereby you will on the native level alter how the Entry field functions to display an icon in its placeholder. To do this you will either need some native expierience on both platforms or some patience and learning about the native platforms.

If you need further help feel free to drop a comment :)

Comment: I'd like the second way since it is native performance.I've tried to write a renderer but there is no docs about the placeholder.all is about the entry.I'v thought of the layer that add a layer to the right position but I do not know how to add it

Comment: For the first way I wonder if there is a software that can extract the fontAwesome file to a small file since I only use one charactor otherwise I have to add a large size file to the project it is not valueable.

Comment: Forget to Thank you for your answer